# Spring Integration - Use SpEL in service-activator nested bean constructor-arg

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

I am trying to use a `factory-method` to initialize a `service-activator` as below

```
<int:service-activator>
    <bean class="com.sample.FileWriterFactory" factory-method="createFileWriter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${xml.out-directory}/xml"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" value="#{ headers['file_name'] + '.xml' }"/>
    </bean>
</int:service-activator>
```

However, the SpEL evaluation fails since the `headers` property is not found in the evaluation context. The exact error snippet is

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'headers' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?

The purpose of doing this is that I want to reuse the same POJO by passing different parameters as needed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#{...}` expressions are evaluated once, during context initialization.

Expressions accessing properties (such as `headers`) like that need to be evaluated at runtime (against the message as the root object).

If that's what you are trying to do, use `value="headers['file_name'] + '.xml'"` and then, within your constructor...

```
private final Expression expression;

public FileWriterFactory(String directory, String expression) {
    ...
    this.expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(expression);
}
```

then, in your runtime service method

```
String fileName = this.expression.getValue(message, String.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @Gary. Worked like a charm!